# How to set Validator not accept selected option of index 0 using angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I using select option like this

```
<div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{'has-error': (!form.controls['blockFirstIndex'].valid && form.controls['blockFirstIndex'].touched), 'has-success': (form.controls['blockFirstIndex'].valid && form.controls['blockFirstIndex'].touched)}">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">blockFirstIndex</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select formControlName="blockFirstIndex" [(ngModel)]="value" class="form-control">
                 <option *ngFor="let item of items" [disabled]="item.id==0" [ngValue]="item">{{item.name}}</option>
            </select>
      </div>
</div>
```

My Validator

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    'blockFirstIndex': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
});
```

How to make validator not accept select option of index 0 ?

Comment: `disabled` should disallow to select a value.. so why you want to configure Validator then?

Comment: right, but on template popup is select the first option. so I want to configure Validator disallow the first option. first option is only hint for other user if the option is --not set-- @PankajParkar

Answer (score 0):

```
Form controller could be like this:

blockFirstIndex: new FormControl("", [
                    SelectionValidator.isValidSelection,
                    Validators.required
                ])

and you can define vlaidator like this:

import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms'; 
    export class SelectionValidator {
       static  isValidSelection(control: FormControl){
            if (control.value === "" || control.value=== "0") {
                return { "Please provide a valid selection": true };
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```